# Splash screen not working in phonegap build

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build

when i set images in ldpi,mdpi,etc.. format. it's not working in android mobile.when i give default splash screen without format it's working.i don't know what i wrongly did.please check and reply me..

```
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-splashscreen" source="npm" spec="~4.0.1" />
<platform name="android">
    <icon density="ldpi" src="www/res/icon/android/drawable-ldpi-icon.png" />
    <icon density="mdpi" src="www/res/icon/android/drawable-mdpi-icon.png" />
    <icon density="hdpi" src="www/res/icon/android/drawable-hdpi-icon.png" />
    <icon density="xhdpi" src="www/res/icon/android/drawable-xhdpi-icon.png" />
    <icon density="xxhdpi" src="www/res/icon/android/drawable-xxhdpi-icon.png" />
    <icon density="xxxhdpi" src="www/res/icon/android/drawable-xxxhdpi-icon.png" />
<splash density="port-ldpi" src="www/res/screen/android/drawable-port-ldpi-screen.png" />
    <splash density="port-mdpi" src="www/res/screen/android/drawable-port-mdpi-screen.png" />
    <splash density="port-hdpi" src="www/res/screen/android/drawable-port-hdpi-screen.png" />
    <splash density="port-xhdpi" src="www/res/screen/android/drawable-port-xhdpi-screen.png" />
    <splash density="port-xxhdpi" src="www/res/screen/android/drawable-port-xxhdpi-screen.png" />
    <splash density="port-xxxhdpi" src="www/res/screen/android/drawable-port-xxxhdpi-screen.png" />

    <splash src="www/res/screen/android/drawable-land-ldpi-screen.png"/>(this screen only it's taking)        

</platform>

<preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="5000" /> 
<preference name="AutoHideSplashScreen" value="true" />
<preference name="ShowSplashScreenSpinner" value="false"/>
<preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen"/>
```

Comment: Refer this http://docs.phonegap.com/phonegap-build/configuring/icons-and-splash/#splashes

Comment: Same here ... :( Documents sucks, syntax seems to be different everywhere, this is like black magic ...

Answer (score 0):

Your default splash screen **must reside in the root of your application folder**. And it **must be named splash.png**.

You will then reference it like this:

```
<splash src="splash.png" />
```

This requirement is specific to PhonegapBuild.